# How to add an image as a plane in Blender 3.0?

Tags: image

I am trying to add an image as a plane in Blender 3.0 but I can't find how.
I have tried shift + A but I can add images only as reference or background. What is the procedure in Blender 3.0 in earlier versions there was an option for it.

What I am trying to do is to render an image in Blender 3.0.

Comment: It's a built-in addon. Search for 'Images as planes' in Preferences > Edit > Addons tab.

Comment: @JohnEason ah thanks, strange that a new version of blender lack this feature which is quite important for me

Comment: That has always been a Blender-supplied addon right back to at least Blender version 2.8.3 so I guess it was enabled in the dim and distant past in the version you were previously using. I guess that you installed 3.0 from scratch rather than updating from your previous Blender version because otherwise the addon settings would have been transferred automatically.

Comment: @JohnEason could you write an answer so I can accept it?

Comment: Ok. Now added as an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That has always been a built-in addon in Blender right back to version 2.8x.
For a new installation of Blender it may not be enabled by default so go to <kbd>Edit</kbd> > <kbd>Preferences</kbd> > <kbd>Addons</kbd> tab, type 'Images' into the search field, and check <kbd>Import Export:Images as Planes</kbd> as shown below.

[image]

The option will then appear on the main <kbd>Add</kbd> menu and the <kbd>⇧ Shift-A</kbd> menu.

[image]